# Having issues with class/service recognition on Laravel forge

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mailchimp

So I'm trying to push my code to forge and on doing so I receive the following error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                     
  Fatal error: Class 'Skovmand\Mailchimp\MailchimpServiceProvider' not found  

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

This is, I believe to the following package: https://github.com/skovmand/mailchimp-laravel.

I'm not sure what could be going wrong here. There doesn't seem to be any issues with the declaration of the service that I've set in the config/app.php file under the service providers like this: `Skovmand\Mailchimp\MailchimpServiceProvider::class`.

So I would appreciate any responses here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, check if files are in a `vendor` directory, they could not be installed. If the files are there, try to run `composer dumpauto -o`.

If command didn't help, try to manually delete autoload files and run the command again.

Comment: ok, thank you. I have tried the first two options to no avail. Now just asking to be sure. Which files exactly should be deleted? And which command should be run again, the dump autoload?

Comment: Yes, `dumpauto` or `dump-autoload` (they are aliases). Also, please look here to understand what files `composer dumpauto` creates: http://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the issue was that I was pulling in the dev version of the packages i was using instead of the stable versions. Common mistake. Remember to place composer package declarations in '`require`' rather than in '`require-dev`' in your composer.json file guys.